# Custom mappings in help text buffers

Tags: vim

I tend not to use windows much in Vim (I prefer tabs), but there are certain things that use them, such as help text buffers. I'm fine with that, but with how seldom I use windows, it usually takes me a second to remember how to close the window (`<C-w>c`) and go back to what I was doing. So I'd like to add a line to my vimrc that maps `q` to close the window, only if the window is a Help buffer.

I've already done something similar for netrw windows, like this:

```
augroup wtf_netrw
  autocmd!
  autocmd filetype netrw nnoremap <buffer> q :e#<CR>
augroup END
```

I tried doing a similar thing with `filetype help`:

```
:autocmd filetype help nnoremap <buffer> q <C-w>c
```

but it didn't work -- typing `q` in a help text buffer just did the default `q` action, recording a macro.

When I try just `:nnoremap q <C-w>c`, typing `q` in a help text buffer closes the window as I expect.

Is there a special way to add a mapping that works only in a help text buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use something like this (borrowed from Junegunn's vimrc, I think):

```
augroup vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter *.txt call s:at_help()
    ...
augroup END

" special actions for help files
function! s:at_help()
    if &buftype == 'help'
        " enable 'q' = quit
        nnoremap <buffer> q :q<cr>
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 5):

Put this in a file `~/.vim/ftplugin/help.vim`:

```
nnoremap <silent> <buffer> q :q<CR>
```

Comment: Both your answer and Laser's are equally good IMHO. Thanks! I can only pick one correct answer though, so I picked Laser because he/she has less rep :)